# why am i getting progress slider exception error

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am making an application which will play audio.I have used a slider to show the time elapsed and time remaining graphically in the slider.But i am not getting how to get the value programitcically.I have used the following code but its throwing an exception.

```
 -(void) updateMyProgress
{
  float progress = [avPlayer currentTime]/[avPlayer duration];
  self.myProgressView.progress = progress;
}
```

The code im my viewcontoller.m file is

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer;
    AVPlayer *avp;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
NSString *stringPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"naat" ofType:@"mp3"];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:stringPath];
  NSError *error;
   avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
  [avPlayer setNumberOfLoops:2];
  [avPlayer setVolume:self.sliderVolumeOutlet.value];
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self      selector:@selector(updateMyProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


 }
/*-(void) updateMyProgress
{
 CGFloat progress = [avPlayer currentTime]/[avPlayer duration];
self.myProgressView.progress = progress;
}
*/
-(void) updateMyProgress

{

AVPlayerItem *currentItem = avp.currentItem ;

CMTime duration = currentItem.duration; //total time
CMTime currentTime = currentItem.currentTime; //playing time

CGFloat progress = currentTime.value/duration.value;

self.myProgressView.progress = progress; 
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)sliderVolumeAction:(id)sender
{
UISlider *myslider= sender;
[avPlayer setVolume:myslider.value];
}

- (IBAction)stopButton:(id)sender
{
[avPlayer stop];
[avPlayer setCurrentTime:0];
}

- (IBAction)pauseButton:(id)sender
{
[avPlayer pause];
}

- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender
{
[avPlayer play];
}
@end![enter image description here][1]
```

The attached image shows the screenshot of the exception

! [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsxtI.png

Comment: which line of code did throw the exception? which expection was thrown?

Comment: can you just post error message here.?

Answer (score 1):

- AVPlayer has no property called "duration".
- "duration" is the property of AVPlayerItem.
- And both duration and currentTime are of "CMTime" dataType
- We have to get the value of CMTime then update the progress.

> -(void) updateMyProgress
>
> ```
> {
>
>     AVPlayerItem *currentItem = avPlayer.currentItem;
>
>     CMTime duration = currentItem.duration; //total time
>     CMTime currentTime = currentItem.currentTime; //playing time
>
>     CGFloat progress = currentTime.value/duration.value;
>
>     self.myProgressView.progress = progress;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.After implementing the method posted by you i am getting this error: Property 'currentItem' not found on object of type 'AVAudioPlayer *' .Please Help

Comment: "currentItem" is the property of AVPlayer not AVAudioPlayer

Comment: I have defined using AvPlayer but am getting exception.
I have pasted viewcontroller.m file.Please help me.

Comment: @user3571734, what have to pasted ?I did not get your question. 

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Chapters/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVPlayer/currentTime
Go through the DOc ,you will find CurrentItem as the property of AVPlayer

Comment: I have pasted the viewcontroller.m file in my main question.

Comment: Ok.Now after using AVPlayer  What exception error message are you getting ?

Comment: (lldb) -This is only written.This link shows the screenshot my xcode.
   http://i.stack.imgur.com/WsxtI.png

Comment: The reason of your crash is : avPlayer is nil.

Comment: In ViewDidLoad Method ,you have assigned AVPlayer to AVAudioPlayer which is  a Incompatible type.
Thats the reason AVPlayer is nil.In your screenshot,its clearly mentioned that avPlayer is nil.

Comment: I think the avPlayer that i have used is the one i have declared earlier in the interface.(AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer;).You mentioned that they are incombatible type so how to make it combatible.Please forgive me for asking such questions but i am a complete newbie.

Comment: See if you want to play audio ,there is one sample app in Github, 
https://github.com/jayaprada-behera/AudioDemo
Refer this .